# New line character does not work in a return string in Python

Tags: python, newline

Here in the below code, I try to do a calculation in a function and then I return all the values in a string to the main program body in Python. The issue here is the new line character \n does not work with my code in the return statement.
What is the reason for that?

```
#create function
def program(value):
    #creat variables
   
    tip_percentage=10
    tip_amount=0
    final_bill=0

    #calculations
    tip_amount=value*tip_percentage/100
    final_bill=value+tip_amount

    #print output  
    x=("value -> \n",value," Tip -> \n",tip_amount,"Total value -> \n",final_bill)
    print(x)
    return x

#Main body
value=int(input("Enter value : "))
value=program(value)
print(value)
```

Tried returning a value from a function. Then in the return statement the \n which is the new line character does not work.

Comment: Why is x a tuple? And even if this does work, why have an arrow, then a newline, and immediately after the nextline? It would look like `value -> ` `4 Tip -> ` `2 Total_value -> `...

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal So then I can print all the things at once. I just want to know why the new line doesn't work in this. Arrows are just to direct and show the value. Using a new line after each result is to show each output in a new line.

Comment: Try using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html): `x = f'value -> {value}\nTip -> {tip_amount}\nTotal value -> {final_bill}\n'`

Comment: I see that you want to separate the values as such, but the way you've done it now would put your value on a new line before the next word instead of next to the arrow. Notice the end and start of the code blocks.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal  I see. That's some reading I have to do. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The Tuple object you return  `x=("value -> \n",value," Tip -> \n",tip_amount,"Total value -> \n",final_bill)`  doesn't not interpret escape sequences like `\n` it deal with it as normal string.

You can return a string instead.

```
x= "value -> \n{}\nTip -> \n{}\nTotal value -> \n{}".format(value, tip_amount, final_bill)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x=("value -> \n",value," Tip -> \n",tip_amount,"Total value -> \n",final_bill)
```

In the above line, you are writing your string as a tuple. You have to convert it to a string.